# using gvisTimeline in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, google-visualization, googlevis

I am new to using GoogleVis library in R and I have a CSV file which I have converted to a data.frame because I am required to feed a data.frame to gvisTimeline. Can you please tell me how should I fix the parameter?

```
prob <- read.csv("_slash_probability.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
plot(gvisTimeline(prob, barlabel="timestamp", rowlabel="fruit",
                  options=list(width=600, height=350))
)
```

Here's the errors I get :

```
Invalid data table format: must have 3 or 4 data columns.×
```

[image]

Here's how my csv file looks like:

```
rosbagTimestamp,data
1438293895271171569,blueberry 0.0939634317574;
1438293895303195547,blueberry 0.0846330225841;
1438293895304291013,blueberry 0.0828378077875;
1438293895337791976,blueberry 0.0797700384253;
1438293895401420350,blueberry 0.0759388571186;
1438293895472735323,blueberry 0.0750429342259;
1438293895476007383,blueberry 0.0750213831086;
1438293895507707571,blueberry 0.075791014733;
1438293895573689503,blueberry 0.0776209483645;
1438293895637463777,blueberry 0.0834959971174;
1438293895641481231,blueberry 0.0879266074843;
1438293895656845822,blueberry 0.0904240066394;
1438293895771521924,blueberry 0.0883910759335;apple 0.0826913130923;
1438293895841645544,blueberry 0.0883910759335;apple 0.0774326788207;
1438293896011836483,strawberry 0.0793898589924;blueberry 0.0883910759335;apple 0.0882327474566;
```

Say as in the last one it says what is the probability that robot is seeing each of the fruits.

UPDATE:
I used this code:

```
prob <- read.csv("_slash_signal.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
plot(gvisTimeline(prob, barlabel="rosbagTimestamp", rowlabel="data",
                  options=list(width=600, height=350))
)
```

for this csv:

```
rosbagTimestamp,data
1438293888221082923,anticipation
1438293894686284247,start
1438293912206205027,reset
1438293951208942248,reset
1438293971527805563,reset
```

I get the same error yet.

Comment: `prob` only has 2 columns because there is only one `,` in each row. I would have thought the error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: sorry, what is obvious for you isn't obvious for me. Other than that I wouldn't have posted it here. Besides I am not sure how can I use 1438293895271171569 for say end or start because it is not of date format. Can't timeline work if there is only two column in my .csv file? or can you tell me how can I use timeline in this example?

Comment: You have to match your data to the format required. You have `rowlabel="fruit"` and `barlabel="timestamp"` in your code, but neither of those columns is in your csv file. Your csv file also has colon and space separators instead of commas, and needs to be reshaped to be like `label,name,start,end` or `label,start,end` as per the examples provided with the R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis_examples.html As for the timestamp, where did it come from? You are in the best position to know what it represents.

Comment: I'm guessing the first 10 characters of the timestamp might represent seconds since the epoch, e.g. `as.POSIXct(1438293895,origin="1970-01-01")` gives a date a week or so ago. The last 9 digits are probably the decimal fractions of a second seeing as they increase steadily until they are >0.99 and then the second increments by 1

Comment: it is the timestamp for the robot. In each timestamp robot sees something and tells with what probability it has seen the item. so it should be something really small. All the timeline examples i saw so far use as.Date. So I am not sure what the solution could be. Also as you see csv has ; which means sometimes robots sees more than one item!

Comment: Do you mean that we cannot use timeline in that time scale?

Comment: You need to read the documentation and try to adapt some of your data into the predefined examples. Even with your edit you are still using 2 columns instead of the required 3 or 4, hence you are getting the same error. And you still haven't made the required start and end date columns as a date/time format outlined in the previous comment. The examples in the inline help at `?gvisTimeline` also has several using POSIXct date/times. Try `as.POSIXct(1438293895.271171569,origin="1970-01-01")` for an example of how your timestamp can be converted to see if it will/won't work with googleVis.

Comment: ok, what if my CSV only has two columns and I want to use timeline to visualize it? Is it not possible to do so?

Comment: Without knowing the googleVis system in-depth, I would probably say it isn't appropriate to use for this circumstance. Maybe search `[r] timeline` here and see if there are any better alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

this seems to work

```
library('googleVis')

dd <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text = "rosbagTimestamp,data
1438293888221082923,anticipation
1438293894686284247,start
1438293912206205027,reset
1438293951208942248,reset
1438293971527805563,reset")

dd <- within(dd, {
  end <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(substr(rosbagTimestamp, 1, 10)),
                    origin = '1970-01-01')
  start <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(substr(rosbagTimestamp, 11, 19)),
                      origin = '1970-01-01')
  rosbagTimestamp <- NULL
})

#           data               start                 end
# 1 anticipation 1977-01-02 14:54:40 2015-07-30 18:04:48
# 2        start 1991-09-30 22:31:28 2015-07-30 18:04:54
# 3        reset 1976-07-14 11:08:48 2015-07-30 18:05:12
# 4        reset 1976-08-15 03:32:16 2015-07-30 18:05:51
# 5        reset 1986-09-22 16:37:20 2015-07-30 18:06:11


plot(gvisTimeline(dd, rowlabel = 'data', barlabel = 'data',
                  start = 'start', end = 'end'))
```

[image]

Comment: I see you have years in the x-axis. Is it like we cannot be using stuff like 1/1000 of a second or less? Did you see the comments provided above by thelatemill regarding using as.POSIXct(1438293895,origin="1970-01-01") ? I wonder if in our specific case, the time we are capturing the robot behavior pr predictions could be used to visualize in Google timeline?

Comment: see when I am running the code, it says like an specific item like anticipation took 38 years, 6 months, 28 days. Is there anyway we could show the realtime it took?

Comment: Also can you please give me a hint that how you could have different names on the y-axis?  because when i ran another (similar csv and same column names) I got this result: http://i.imgur.com/8lLg5l7.png (items are banana, strawberry, blueberry and kiwi)

Comment: please disregard above and look at here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846963/google-vis-timeline-aggregation thanks for the help

Comment: like @thelatemail said, you need to know that. if you divide the "dates" by 1e8 then you get seconds instead of years, so you can make it any increment of time you want, ie, divide by 1e6 and you get minutes. the names along the y are given by `rowlabel` since you have labels which are identical, bananas, you get the same label and all those with identical labels are grouped together